# create object from dynamic classname - ReflectionClass in JS?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to do something like this without evil eval:

```
var str='MyClass';
eval('new '+str);
```

i just learned that there's ReflectionClass in PHP...
thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var str = "MyClass";
var obj = new window[str];
```

Here's an example:

```
function MyClass() {
   console.log("constructor invoked");
}

var s = "MyClass";
new window[s]; //logs "constructor invoked"
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!
EDIT: ooh, and I can put the class definitions into an object, instead of using the window object...

Answer (score 5):

Create object (invoke constructor) via reflection:

```
SomeClass = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
}

ReflectUtil.newInstance('SomeClass', 5, 7);
```

and implementation:

```
/**
 * @param strClass:
 *          class name
 * @param optionals:
 *          constructor arguments
 */
ReflectUtil.newInstance = function(strClass) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var clsClass = eval(strClass);
    function F() {
        return clsClass.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = clsClass.prototype;
    return new F();
};
```

Comment: It's *only* bad if you do not properly validate the string being `eval`ed. Aside from that, this answer is great. The currently accepted answer *only* works if the class is globally accessible (i.e., at the window level). Classes defined within closures, for instance, cannot be instantiated using the `window` method.

Comment: @ElliotB. In that case, you can use `this` to reference the current scope. a la `new this[className]`

Comment: @JacobRelkin That doesn't appear to work. I constructed a test with scope referenced in a couple different ways: http://jsfiddle.net/d84bh/1/ It only works for me when the class is defined at the global/window level: http://jsfiddle.net/d84bh/2/