# Creating an object in javascript dynamically?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create object from dynamic classname - ReflectionClass in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085095/create-object-from-dynamic-classname-reflectionclass-in-js)

Is it possible to do this in javascript?

```
var objectName = "object";
var object = new objectName();
```

or something along these lines?

Comment: As am not i am pointed out, yes, to an extent. Why exactly do you need this, though?

Comment: Better use Factory to create objects.

Answer (score 7):

If the constructor is defined globally...

```
var object = new window[objectName]();
```

---

If not, you'd need to use `eval` or the `Function` constructor. Before you did that, I'd try to find a different way to do what you're doing.

Comment: +1 the OP would need correct casing in his example also; `var objectName = "Object";`

Comment: @AlexK.: You're right, assuming the native `Object` constructor is desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can archieve that using [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). 
Eval basically interprets a string like it were a script line. Althought, some developers consider it's a dangerous function to your daily use, other's don't. Read more [here](http://berniesumption.com/software/eval-considered-useful/).

Example of your code using eval (corrected):

```
var objectName = "Object";
var object = new (eval(objectName));
eval("object.name = \"Nice!\""); // you don't need this, just an example of eval capabilities

document.write(object.name);
```

Running: http://jsfiddle.net/RxNsd/4/

Comment: Don't downvote this answer. It's the **only** solution for **local** constructors.

Comment: @RobW agree, if there is no reasonable alternatives to using eval to achieve something then eval or eval-likes are fine =)

Comment: People freak out when they see `eval`. I don't know why. A person could also use the `Function` constructor, but its still effectively evaling the string. `Function('return new ' + objectName + '()')()`

Comment: @RobW: You need to wrap the `eval` call in `()`. `new (eval(objectName));` Otherwise the `eval` function itself becomes the single operand of `new`.

Comment: @amnotiam That's correct. The right usafe is `var objectName = "Object";var object = new (eval(objectName));`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible the way you coded. But with a little change...

```
var object = { objectName: "object" };
alert(object.objectName); // Pops up "object"
```

If you prefer the `new` syntax, there must exist a constructor function.

```
function ObjectName(name) // This is the "constructor" function
{
    this.objectName = name;
}

var object = new ObjectName("object");
alert(object.objectName); // Pops up "object"
```